# Cómo es que puedo guardar datos en arreglos en PHP?

Tags: php

Mi objetivo es que se una serie de cadenas y una serie de números se almacenen en dos Arrays distinto, pero cuando ejecuto el programa no sucede nada. Me fijé si los arreglos estaban recibiendo datos, y resulta que su longitud siempre es 0 = no están recibiendo datos.

```
function AnalisisMatriz($matriz,$numero, $cam, $Caminos, $Pesos)
{
    $menor = 0;
    $iteracion = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<$numero-1;$i++)
    {
        for($j = 0; $j< $numero-1; $j++)
        {
            if($i == 0 && $j == 0)
            {
                $menor = Menorcamino($matriz, $i, $j, $numero -1 , $numero -1, 0, $numero, $cam);
            }
            else
            {
                if($i != $numero -1 && $j != $numero -1)
                {
                    $menor = Menorcamino($matriz, $i, $j, $numero -1 , $numero -1, 0, $numero, $cam);
                    $aux = Menorcamino($matriz, 0,0, $i , $j, 0, $numero, $cam);
                    $menor = $aux - $matriz[$i][$j];
                }
            }
            $cam = $cam . "(".($numero-1).",".($numero-1)."):";
            $Caminos[$iteracion] = $cam;
            $Pesos[$iteracion][] = $menor;
            $cam = "";
            $iteracion = $iteracion +1 ;
        }
    }
}
```

He intentado colocar, por ejemplo en el Array Pesos, Pesos[iteracion][0] porque recordé que así mismo imprimí una matriz. Aun así no he tenido éxito.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tenemos tu función, pero necesitaríamos tener un ejemplo con datos de entrada y los datos que se esperan a la salida.

Comment: No estás retornando nada de esa función. Y los cambios en los arrays no ocurrirán si no los pasas por referencia. De todos modos, faltan detalles en tu pregunta, por ejemplo, ¿desde qué contexto llamas a la función? ¿qué depuraciones has hecho?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor sigue las recomendaciones que te sugirió @OscarGarcia. Tu método no ofrece una salida. `return $variable` imagino que no lo hace porque alimenta la matriz $matriz y el array $Pesos y esperas que alojen los datos. **Supongo** que debes pasarlas por referencia haciendo: `function AnalisisMatriz(&$matriz,$numero, $cam, $Caminos, &$Pesos){ ... }` En php los  **los arrays son pasados a los métodos por valor** necesitas hacer explícito el paso por referencia.